# How do I compare a commit in history with unmodified code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

In History in VS, I can pick a class in a commit, right click, and choose 'Compare with Previous', or compare the class through different commits. There is no option, however, to Compare with Unmodified. The latter only exists with the latest commit.

I want the latter, but with the file in a different SHA.

Comment: What plugin/service are you using for committing code from VS - TFS, AnkhSVN? Or is it some built in service?

Comment: `git diff <SHA-of-commit> [file]` would give you a diff from your working directory and `<SHA-of-commit>` rather than the diff between two commits. The `[file]` is optional, other wise the whole repo is compared

Comment: @MattStannett I am not using any third party solution, VS detected a .git folder in my solution and integrated it.